# How to give outside arguments to a thread (in realtime)?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

**Background**

I am trying to code a solution to a problem on [Raspberry Pi Stackexchange.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6981/6609) The person is creating a kiosk, and wants Midori (A browser on Raspbian Wheezy) to reload itself if a network disconnects and then reconnects. To check the internet connectivity, I have decided to  have the program attempt to connect to Google. I use a variable `up` which is assigned to 0 (down) or 1 (up) depending on the state of the connection.

I am having issues sending the new reassigned `up` variable to the thread. I am getting a perpetual stream of "Up has not been reassigned" from my thread.

**Code**

```
up = -1 #Undefined state

test_net = ("www.google.com", 80)

#Import modules
import subprocess as sub
from time import sleep
import socket
import threading

def reloader(up):
    print "A new thread is born." #Debug
    while True:
        if up == 1:
            print "The system is up."
        elif up == 0:
            print "The system is down."
            #sub.call(["midori", "-e", "Reload"])
        else:
            print "Up has not been reassigned."
        sleep(5)



#Check if internet is up

threading.Thread(target = reloader, args = (up,)).start()

while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect(test_net)
        up = 1
        print up
    except socket.error:
        up = 0
        print up
    s.close()
    sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is a misunderstanding of how arguments are passed to functions in Python. You are expecting that when you do

```
up = 1
```

or

```
up = 0
```

from within the global scope, the `reloader` function will see the change reflected in the `up` variable within its scope, since you passed that variable to it as an argument. That ain't how it works.

You passed the `reloader` function *the object that the `up` name in the global scope pointed to* as an argument, and then you assigned a *new object* to that name in the global scope. The `up` name in the `reloader` scope still points to the object it was originally passed, which is the integer `-1`.

You have two options here to get the behavior that you want:

**1. Share state by closure, instead of by passing arguments**

If you make the following two changes to your code, everything will work the way you expect:

- Replace `def reloader(up):` with `def reloader():`
- Replace `threading.Thread(target = reloader, args = (up,)).start()` with `threading.Thread(target = reloader, args = ()).start()`

Why? Because functions in Python can refer to all the names defined in their parent scope. When you were requiring `reloader` to take an argument named `up`, you were defining a local variable `up` within `reloader` and thereby hiding the same-named variable in the parent scope. But if you simply remove the argument, then when you try to read `up` from within `reloader`, Python will see that there is no such *local* variable and look in the parent scope instead. Hence, assignments to `up` in the outer scope will be visible within `reloader`.

***or***

**2. Share state by mutating an object that is passed as an argument**

Instead of passing the integer `-1` to `reloader` as an argument, pass a mutable object that contains  `-1`, and then modify the object wherever you would currently assign a new object to `up`. One hack that you'll see suggested from time to time (usually when people want assignments made to a variable within a function to be visible from the outer scope; you, unusually, have the opposite problem, which can only occur when using threads) is to wrap the variable in a list (that is, initialize `up` as `[-1]` instead of `-1`, and thereafter always refer to `up[0]` instead of `up` except when passing it as an argument to functions), and this will work in this case.

Alternatively, a less ugly mutable-object-based solution might be to use the [`Value` class from the multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value), which exists for precisely this purpose. (Note that sharing state between *processes* by closure is not possible in the way that it is for threads, making using mutable objects to share state much more necessary when using multiprocessing. Perhaps that is why the multiprocessing module has the `Value` class but the threading module does not - so far as I know - have anything similar.)

Working code using this approach would look like this:

```
test_net = ("www.google.com", 80)

#Import modules
import subprocess as sub
from time import sleep
import socket
import threading
from multiprocessing import Value

up = Value('i', -1) #Undefined state

def reloader(up):
    print "A new thread is born." #Debug
    while True:
        if up.value == 1:
            print "The system is up."
        elif up.value == 0:
            print "The system is down."
            #sub.call(["midori", "-e", "Reload"])
        else:
            print "Up has not been reassigned."
        sleep(5)



#Check if internet is up

threading.Thread(target = reloader, args = (up,)).start()

while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect(test_net)
        up.value = 1
        print up
    except socket.error:
        up.value = 0
        print up
    s.close()
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: This is all actually a lot simpler than the length of this answer makes it seem, and chances are there will be just one or two sentences here - perhaps early on - that make you suddenly 'get it' in a flash of clarity and render the entire rest of the answer obvious to you. It's hard to be sure though at precisely which point you've stumbled conceptually so I have little choice but to be thorough. :)